# How to get attribute value of the main parent node element from a child element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

is it possible to get the attribute 'data-id' when clicking on a child element? In the scenario below, the `getDataIdOfTheCurrentRow()` method only firs when clicking on the span, not the whole record. I need to retrieve the attr value of the the parent `tr`. I know I can set a method that fires when clicking on the 'tr' so I can easily access its attributes. but this is not what I am asking for.

```
 <tr data-id="1">
     <div>
          <div>
              <div id="text-wrapper">
                  <span onclick="getDataIdOfTheCurrentRow(event)">some text</span>
              </div>
          </div>
     </div>
 </tr>


function getDataIdOfTheCurrentRow(event) {
   // stopPropagation is used to only fires the method when clicking on the child element, not other methods on the parent elements
    event.stopPropagation(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `closest(selector)`:

```js
function getDataIdOfTheCurrentRow(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    const row = event.target.closest('tr');
    if(row.hasAttribute('data-id')){
      const dataID = row.getAttribute('data-id');
      // now do your thing
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I want. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

- The only valid parent tag of a `<tr>` is a `<table>`

  *Wrap everything in a `<table>`*
- The only children tag a `<tr>` can have is `<td>` and `<th>`

  *Add a `<td>` directly within `<tr>` remove those extra `<div>` they will only clutter your layout*
- Do not use `id` so liberally, you'll understand when you've written your hundredth page and have a hard time overriding styles, adding JavaScript that references DOM objects, etc.

  *Remove all `id`s and use `document.querySelector()` to reference elements by  `.class`, `[name]`, `tagName`, etc.*
- Don't use inline event handlers<sup>❋</sup>

  ```html
   <div class='target' onclick="lame(this)">DON'T DO THIS</div>
  ```

  Use onevent properties or

  ```js
  document.querySelector('.target').onclick = eventHandler;
  ```

  event listeners

  ```js
  document.querySelector('.target').addEventListener('click', eventHandler)
  ```

<sup>❋</sup><sup>See below for links to articles about events</sup>

***Details are commented in example***

```js
// Bind click event to an ancestor tag
document.querySelector('table').onclick = getRow;

// Event handlers only passes the Event object
function getRow(event) {
  // Reference the tag that the user clicked
  const clicked = event.target;
  // If the clicked tag is a <button>...
  if (clicked.matches('button')) {
    /*
    Find the closest parent <tr> get it's data-id value and convert it 
    into a real number
    */
    console.log(parseInt(clicked.closest('tr').dataset.id));
  }
}
```

```css
.as-console-row::after {
  width: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

.as-console-row-code {
  width: 100%;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100% !important;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr data-id="1">
    <td>
      <menu>
        <button type='button'>Get row number</button>
      </menu>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-id='2'>
    <td>
      <menu>
        <button type='button'>Get row number</button>
      </menu>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-id='3'>
    <td>
      <menu>
        <button type='button'>Get row number</button>
      </menu>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-id='4'>
    <td>
      <menu>
        <button type='button'>Get row number</button>
      </menu>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)

[Event Delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation)

[Inline event handlers are garbage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these)